# ADA Compliance Issue with my Code

Tags: wcag

My site was recently scanned for ADA compliance and there is one particular issue that I can't seem to figure out how to fix. The error I am getting is "Adjacent links are not separated properly." Below is the code that it is referring too.

```
<ul class="desktop-nav hidden-sm hidden-xs hide-on-tablet">
                            <li><a href="#" title="Home"><span class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> home
                            <small>our home page</small></a></li>
                            <li id="mega-menu-1-hover"><a href="#" title="Accounts"><span class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></span> accounts <small>checking &amp; savings</small></a></li>
                            <li id="mega-menu-2-hover"><a href="#" title="Loans"><span class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"v></span> loans <small>what do you need?</small></a></li>
                            <li id="mega-menu-3-hover"><a href="#" title="Services"><span class="fa fa-gears" aria-hidden="true"></span> services <small>what can we do for you?</small></a></li>
                            <li id="mega-menu-4-hover"><a href="#" title="About Us"><span class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span> about us <small>who we are</small></a></li>
                            <li id="mega-menu-5-hover"><a href="#" title="Forms"><span class="fa fa-file-text" aria-hidden="true"></span> forms <small>apply online today</small></a></li>
                        </ul>
```

Please someone help me figure this problem out!

Comment: Have you considered closing your hyperlinks before the end of their containing list items?  Say, before the `<small>` text?

Comment: Yes, and that didn't work. I also tried removing the <small> text completely and it didn't work either. I want to keep the <small> text though.

Comment: Hmm.  The links you present *are* separated -- in different list items -- and reducing the link text to cover only part of each item separates them more.  Do the scanner's docs or does its report not associate this message with a specific guideline you can check?  Maybe it wants text between each `<li>` start tag and the following `<a>` start tag?

Comment: Yeah that isn't working either. I did find out that it is a WCAG 1.0 (Level AAA) issue, so should I even worry about that?

Comment: An AAA-level issue is one that the guidelines say "may" be addressed, as opposed to "should" or "must" be addressed.  Fixing it will make your site more accessible, but it is not an overwhelming problem.

Comment: It appears that the specific issue is probably item 5 of WCAG 1.0 guideline 10: "Until user agents (including assistive technologies) render adjacent links distinctly, include non-link, printable characters (surrounded by spaces) between adjacent links."  The W3C has [a few suggestions on ways to do that](https://www.w3.org/TR/WAI-WEBCONTENT-TECHS/#tech-divide-links).

Comment: Consider also that the issue might not be between the hyperlinks in your list, but between the first or last one and a preceding or following link.

Comment: Thanks for the help in this matter!